# Results from two tables as rows, joining a third for additional columns

Tags: sql, join, union, db2-400

Trying to pull data from 3 tables : `warpall, warpalq, warcmdt`

I wish to return data from `warpall`/`warpalq` as rows in the same result (so `warpall` data first then `warpalq` data below), joining `warcmdt` as it has descriptions in it that I need to return. I can't union them as one field I need isn't present in `warpalq`.

Could someone advise on how to approach this?

```
select clntpm, pal#pm, clsspm, clsqpm, **commpm**  from warpall
where <criteria>

select clntpq, pal#pq, clsspq, clsqpq from warpalq
where <different criteria>

join warcmdt on warcmdt.clntcd = warpall.clntpm and warcmdt.commcd = 
warpall.commpm
```

--- Edit

The syntax I now have is;

```
select 
  * from (select substr(warpall.clntpm,1,2) as clntwf, 
substr(warpall.pal#pm,1,10) as pal#wf, commpm, substr(warpall.clsspm,1,2) as 
clsswf, warpall.clsqpm * 1 as clsqwf from warpall

where locnpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
and commpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
and clsqpm <> 0

union all

select substr(clntpq,1,2) as clntwf, substr(pal#Pq,1,10) as pal#wf, null 
commpm, substr(clsspq,1,2) as clsswf, clsqpq * 1 as clsqwf from warpalq
where clsqpq <> 0
) as t9
inner join 
  warcmdt as t3
on 
  t3.clntcd = t9.clntwf  and t3.commcd = t9.commpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. As400/db2 needed '0' for null columns.

```
select 
clntwf, commpm, fdsccd, clsqf, pal#wf, dtcdpm, clsswf, srb#pm, descsc
from (select substr(warpall.clntpm,1,2) as clntwf,
substr(warpall.pal#pm,1,10) as pal#wf, commpm, 
substr(warpall.clsspm,1,2) as clsswf, warpall.clsqpm * 1 as clsqwf, 
srb#pm, dtcdpm from warpall

where locnpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
and commpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
and clsqpm <> 0

union all

select substr(clntpq,1,2) as clntwf, substr(pal#pq,1,10) as pal#wf, '0', 
substr (clsspq,1,2) as clsswf, clsqpq * 1 as clsqwf, '0', '0' from warpalq
where clsqpq <> 0
) as t9
Inner join
warcmdt as t3
on 
t3.clntcd = t9.clntwf 
and 
t3.commcd = t9.commpm
inner join
warclss as t4
on
t4.clsssc = t9.clsswf

order by pal#wf asc
```